# Nodejs 404 on angular state api, ui-router

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I have nodejs angular app. Nodejs is running server. I have a ui router setup with html5mode on when i go to http://localhost:3000/superadmin node is giving 404, but when i got to http://localhost:3000/#/superadmin it redirects to http://localhost:3000/superadmin and page shows fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell express to redirect all requests that come to the server to your index.html

Example in your server.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.all('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('index.html'); // or the name of your angular app html file
});

app.listen(3000);
```

You need to make sure that you put app.all() below all other routes that you have defined in your express app.